# Angular - Service data not passed between component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm coming to you totally desperate ... Since 1 day, I try to pass data between my two component using a service.

I've already use this service in another application and I know that it's work.

But I've try all the things that I've found with Googling : BehaviorSubject, Subject ... But nothing work in my case : The value is changed in the service thanks to the first component, but nothing happens in the second component, even if I'd subscribe to the value in service.

The second component get the value on init, but nothing after ...

Good to know : The second component is the parent of the first component.

This is my code (Actually) :

GlobalFn.Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class globalFnService{
    id:any;
    activeDeepView = new Subject<boolean>();
    constructor() { 
      this.activeDeepView.next(false);
     }

    deepView(){
      this.activeDeepView.next(!this.activeDeepView);
    }

    getValue(): Observable<any> {
        return this.activeDeepView.asObservable();
    }

}
```

First component (Child) :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { globalFnService } from '../services/globalFn.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profil',
  templateUrl: './profil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profil.component.scss'],
  providers: [globalFnService]
})
export class ProfilComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private globalFn:globalFnService
  ) { 

   }

  deepView(){
    this.globalFn.deepView();
    console.log("clicked !");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalFn.getValue().subscribe(value => {
      if(value == true){
        console.log("status",value);
      } else {
        console.log("status",value);
      }
    })
  }

}
```

The second component (The parent one) :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { globalFnService } from '../services/globalFn.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor(
    private globalFn:globalFnService
  ) { 
    this.subscription = this.globalFn.getValue().subscribe(value => {
      if(value == true){
        console.log("status",value);
      } else {
        console.log("status",value);
      }
    }) 
   }

}
```

If you can find where I do a mistake, you are in capacity to save my day ...

Thank you !

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: have must have to provide service in module ```providers: [globalFnService]```

Comment: show app.module.ts

Comment: I've forget to add it in my app.module.ts ... I'll try to add it and I come to you !

Comment: @PositivProd Do not add it to your app module.

Comment: can you make a stackblitz

Comment: @PositivProd Remove it from Component and add it in app.module.ts, it will work

Comment: When do you call deepView in the child component?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I've try what you say and it's work (Can you write it in new answer ? I'll validate it) ! Thank you for help to all of us, it save my day !

Comment: @PositivProd added

Comment: @PositivProd Try Evan's answer if it doesnot work then try another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sharing data between components, what you all need is to create a service and register it in the parent module (which will work as a singleton instance), so that can available across all the components:

Change that needs to apply:

app.module.ts:

```
import { globalFnService } from '../services/globalFn.service'; // imports

providers: [
   ...,
   globalFnService
]
```

No need to add the reference to any other places: (in other component's provider's array).

Comment: Adding the service to the providers here is also unnecessary, since the service itself is decorated with `  providedIn: 'root'`

Comment: @EvanOgra yes, [Check it](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Comment: Thank you, but even if I have providedIn:'root' it's not work until I import it in my app.module.ts in providers ...

Comment: @EvanOgra At one point, I was also shocked! [Unable to reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-data-sharing-service-44n2sw). Am I missing something?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale You have Angular v5 installed in your stackblitz, which doesn't support the providedIn syntax

Comment: @ShamPooSham Still not able to reproduce with angular 9

Answer (score 1):

When you put `providers: [globalFnService]`, you are telling Angular to instantiate a fresh `globalFnService` and inject it into the component, rather than inject the existing instance of the service. Remove that from the component and it should work.

Comment: dont remove it from a component it should be present there also

Comment: @HitechHitesh No, it should not. The service is decorated as `providedIn: 'root'`. It should not be added to any `providers` (unless you want a different instance of that service).